# References for estimates $E[|X_t|^{2n}]$ and $E[|X_t-X_{t_0}|^{2n}]$ of SDE

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I'm reading this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2163109/proof-for-moment-estimates-of-ito-stochastic-differential-equation) where the following results are mentioned.

---

Given a Ito-SDE
$$dX_t=a(t,X_t)dt+b(t,X_t)dW_t$$
fulfilling the Lipshitz condition and linear growth condition. Then for some constants $C,D$:

- $$
  E\left[\sup_{t_0\le s \le T} |X_s|^{2n}\right]\le D \cdot (E[|X_{t_0}|^{2n}]+(1+E[|X_{t_0}|^{2n}]) \cdot  (T-t_0)^n \exp(C(T-t_0))).
  $$
- $$
  E[|X_t|^{2n}] \le (1+E[|X_{t_0}|^{2n}]) \exp(C(t-t_0)).
  $$
- $$
  E[|X_t-X_{t_0}|^{2n}] \le D \cdot  (1+E[|X_{t_0}|^{2n}]) \cdot (t-t_0)^n \cdot  \exp(C(t-t_0)).
  $$

---

Could you elaborate on the references for the proofs of those estimates?

Comment: Yes, you can use Burkholder inequality and then Grownwall inequality eg. see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280256/application-of-the-burkholder-davis-gundy-inequality